# Migrating from static array to dynamic array

Tags: delphi, matrix

Previously i have static array for the matrix dataset design

```
TMatrix = record
    row, column: word; {m columns ,n strings }
    Data: array[1..160, 1..160] of real

 var
 Mymatrix  : TMatrix;

 begin

 Mymatrix.row := 160; - maximum size for row us is 160 for 2 x 2 static design.
 Mymatrix.columns := 160; -  maximum size for column us is 160  for 2 x 2 static design.
```

With the current design i can only have 160 x 160 in 2 dimensional matrix design. If i enter more array size [1..161, 1..161] , the compiler will alert for E2100 Data type too large: exceeds 2 GB error. So if i convert the code into dynamic array , i need to re-structure all my current code to read the matrix starts from 0 . Previoulsy , for static array the array will starts from 1. Some external functions it start to read the matrix from 1.

So , now i'm stuck with my current code which  i need to create more than thousand N x N matrix size . With my current static array design everything went fine if below than 160 x 160 . So , i need to get any solutions without too much to change my current static array design.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a bigger issue here! If 161x161 is greater than 2GB, switching to a dynamic array won't help because the maximum allocation size for a Win32 process is 2GB. Unless you go to 64bit, you're pretty-much stuck!

Comment: `161*161*SizeOf(Real)` is certainly not greater than 2GB

Comment: Size of TMatrix with 161x161 is 207376 bytes.

Comment: You should be able to compile `Data: array[1..16383, 1..16383] of real;`.

Comment: @David, Sertac: Unless `real` is redefined as something else (which is not very likely, but possible).

Comment: @AndriyM not possible but next to mandatory. Unless legacy `{$Real48 on}` was issued, by the very definition `type real = double;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's going to be easier to continue using 1-based indexing. You can do that a few different ways. For example:

```
type
  TMatrix = record
  private
    Data: array of array of Real;
    function GetRowCount: Integer;
    function GetColCount: Integer;
    function GetItem(Row, Col: Integer): Real;
    procedure SetItem(Row, Col: Integer; Value: Real);
  public      
    procedure SetSize(RowCount, ColCount: Integer);
    property RowCount: Integer read GetRowCount;
    property ColCount: Integer read GetColCount;
    property Items[Row, Col: Integer]: Real read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end;

function TMatrix.GetRowCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(Data)-1;
end;

function TMatrix.GetColCount: Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(Data) then
    Result := Length(Data[0])-1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

procedure TMatrix.SetSize(RowCount, ColCount: Integer);
begin
  SetLength(Data, RowCount+1, ColCount+1);
end;

function TMatrix.GetItem(Row, Col: Integer): Real;
begin
  Assert(InRange(Row, 1, RowCount));
  Assert(InRange(Col, 1, ColCount));
  Result := Data[Row, Col];
end;

procedure TMatrix.SetItem(Row, Col: Integer; Value: Real);
begin
  Assert(InRange(Row, 1, RowCount));
  Assert(InRange(Col, 1, ColCount));
  Data[Row, Col] := Value;
end;
```

The trick here is that even though the dynamic array uses 0 based indexing, you simply ignore the values stored in the 0 index. If ever you are porting code from Fortran which uses 1-based indexing, this approach is generally the most effective.

Comment: +1 but why have an extra row and column? I would have thought the use of the record and its getters and setters would be sufficient to do the index conversion? Only reason I can think of otherwise is debug time matching of indexes on the outside to indexes on the inside?

Comment: @MarjanVenema You can certainly do the 0 to 1 based index shift in the getter and setter. That's perfectly viable. However, it does incur a performance penalty with lots of +1 and -1 in indexing code. Often that doesn't matter, but sometimes it does. In my case, in my codebase, matrices like these are at the heart of my codes algorithms and even a performance drop of a couple of percent matters.

Comment: Ah, getting performance at the sacrifice of a bit of data space... Me like :)

Comment: @MarjanVenema I do wonder how Fortran implementations deal with this. Given the high importance of efficiency for typical Fortran code, it would be surprising if 1-based Fortran arrays and matrices had to pay this +1 indexing penalty.

Comment: Looks like i found the solution now. Thank you for all the helps guys. The codes work like a charm with minimal modification.

Comment: Gosh, Fortran, that rings some bells, albeit very old ones. Think the last time I dealt with it was back in 1986. But yes, it would be interesting to know. If Fortran arrays are always 1-based, the compiler probably has a hand in it. I always felt 0-based arrays are mainly there to assist in offset calculations: x-times element-size where you could then simply fill in the index for x instead of x - 1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the Fortran compilers could easily offset the base address of the array with size of one array element, so effectively this would have no impact on speed. Since Fortran-77 it was also possible to have arrays starting with any index, same as in pascal.